# I can't get state into a function on my phone, but I can when developing and testing on my laptop

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make a reset password page in my Ionic/React mobile app.  This is the code:

```
const ResetPass = () => {

    const [simpleEmail, setSimpleEmail] = useState("")
    const emailsend =() => {
        alert(`this is the simple email example ${simpleEmail}`)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('inside the useEffect')
    },[simpleEmail])

    return (
    <IonPage className={styles.resetPage}>
        <IonContent fullscreen>
            <IonCardTitle className={styles.movedown}>Reset Password</IonCardTitle>

        <IonItemDivider>
<IonItem>
<IonLabel>Email simple</IonLabel>
<IonInput type='email' value={simpleEmail} onIonChange={e => setSimpleEmail(e.detail.value)} />
</IonItem>

        </IonItemDivider>

        <IonButton onClick={emailsend}>check if email goes through</IonButton>
        </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
    )
};
```

On my laptop, when I enter an email into the IonInput, then click on the button I get the alert and it gives me the email I entered.

When I bring this to my phone, after clicking on the button it doesn't give me the email that I entered.

Why could this be?

edit:

so an ugly fix for this is if I add a separate IonInput field in and type something in it then the email gets passed to the function.  I just threw something in like this:

```
        <IonItemDivider>
<IonItem>
<IonLabel>Dummy</IonLabel>
<IonInput type='email' value={dummy} onIonChange={e => setDummy(e.detail.value)} />
</IonItem>

        </IonItemDivider>
```

There's got to be a way of making this work without another field that you just put in for no reason.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try 'ionChange' instead of 'onIonChange'?